# Recover deleted oracle flashback point

Tags: oracle, flashback

I have accidentally deleted a flashback point in a oracle 11g database,Is there a way to recover the restore point

PS:If I have a **flashback point A** which was created **first**, and **flashback point B** which was created **later**.If I drop **flashback point B** and flashback to **flashback point A** will I be able to recover **flashback point B**.

PPS: there are no other backups to recover from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get the restore point back, but if you want to flashback the database you can use `FLASHBACK DATABASE TO SCN <number>` instead. If you know the approximate time you want to revert to you can get the SCN with `TIMESTAMP_TO_SCN`. This assumes that the data is still there, of course. If not it is gone.